# Inheritance from non abstract class

Tags: oop, inheritance, abstraction

As far as I know, the base type of the inheritance hierarchy, continence the general fields and methods that will be the essential ones in order to consider the derived classes as same type of the base type. (correct me if I'm wrong please).

So the question is, since the base type contains generalization of the sub type, shouldn't we consider all the base classes as abstract? since they only describe how a type should behave and what essential elements it should contain in order to be considers from the specified type, isn't this the true essence of an abstraction ?

If my claims are correct, then why OOP languages didn't enforce the deceleration of a base class in the inheritance chain as an abstract? why they allow us to inherit from non abstract types?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. Base class can be fully functional class on its own and it still makes sense to subclass such class to change some particular behavior.

Comment: But sir, since you are inheriting it from another class, don't you think that must mean you are inheriting from an entity which is abstract, I know that the environment modeling detriments the level of the abstraction, but don't you think since it is such an entity which have been considered to be base type, that it should become an abstract ?

Comment: No. Think of UI controls, widgets. You commonly have non abstract base class that carries full implementation for all common UI widget behaviors. It makes no sense for such base class that carries so much implementation details to be abstract. If you start with widget as abstract class you would most likely end up with additional base class on top of it from which all widgets would inherit.

Comment: Let's assume you have this abstract base class from which you have derived your subclass that is not abstract, it can be instantiated, etc. etc. It's been in use for 5 years but now we have decided that we need a second version identical to your subclass but which formats the output differently for people who can't see well. The solution of course is to subclass your subclass and override the `print` method. Is your subclass all of a sudden an incomplete abstract class just because we inherited from it? Of course not! Base classes are non-abstract if they are in some sense *complete*.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson I think the solution is not to subclass 
 the subclass, yet to use composition and provide the print method behavior via dependency injection, since the need rises to use horizontal reuse (Ie: not all the sub-classes use the base default functionality). I think deriving from the sub-classes is not the best option to keep your code clean, yet to use strategy pattern, and provide the necessary behavior in separate classes which drive from common interface that describe the behavior, I think what will be in the base classes shall be common for all derived types.

Answer (score -2):

Abstract class is used to inherit in the child class. An abstract class cannot be inherited by structures. It can contains constructors or destructors. It can implement functions with non-Abstract methods.